# An inequality about metric spaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, inequalities, limits-and-convergence, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces

I started studying this article(《$L^2$ CURVATURE BOUNDS ON MANIFOLDS WITH BOUNDED RICCI CURVATURE》) about 3 months ago: arxiv.org/abs/1605.05583

In this article, there is a seemingly simple assertion on page 27 that troubled me for several days:

"The statement $(1)$ follows now easily by the combination of $(3.39)$ and $(3.41)$."

In fact, I think there are some mistakes here.

The three conclusions are as follows:
$(1)$. $ (1 - \epsilon )d(x,y)^{\epsilon} \le \frac{|\Phi (x) - \Phi (y)|}{d(x,y)} \le d(x,y)^{-\epsilon} $, 
$(3.39)$. $ |\Phi (x) - \Phi^\alpha (y)| \le \eta^{4+2\alpha -2\alpha\eta} $, 
$(3.41)$. $ (1 - \eta^3 )(1 + \eta^2)^{-\alpha } \le \frac{|\Phi^\alpha (x) - \Phi^\alpha (y)|}{d(x,y)} \le (1 + \eta^3 )(1 + \eta^2)^{\alpha } $, 
where $\Phi = \lim_{\alpha \to \infty }\Phi^\alpha$, $\eta \in (0,1)$, $\eta^{2+2\alpha } < d(x,y) \le \eta^{2\alpha } $. (By the definitions in page 20 and page 25, $r_{x}^{\beta} = t_{\beta } = \eta^{2\beta}$ when $x\in C_{0}$. )

Consider the left side of inequality $(1)$. Apply $(3.39)$ and $(3.41)$ directly, we have:
$$\frac{|\Phi (x) - \Phi (y)|}{d(x,y)} \ge (1 - \eta^3 )(1 + \eta^2)^{-\alpha } - \eta^{2-2\alpha\eta}.$$

When $\alpha$ is large enough, the right side of the inequality becomes negative, so I cannot get $(1)$.

Because this article was accepted by Annals, I think this statement should be right. Is there any special inequality technique to be used here?

Thank you!